# Need help in copying a file from local machine to remote machine using java

Tags: java, selenium, jenkins

I have one csv file in my workspace which i need to copy to another machine where the selenium grid running and so that the test can use it while executing scripts. please suggest a way to copy these files?

Comment: another machine has ftp running? you have to give more details

Comment: If you are copying files within same Jenkins "cluster", I would suggest using [Copy Artifact Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Copy+Artifact+Plugin). If not, as @Sanj already suggested, please provide more information about your workflow.

Comment: You should use an SSH or FTP client depending on the installed services on the server. Note that if you are using your file for an upload on a website, you can use the path directly in `.sendKeys`.

Comment: Another option is `scp` if you're on unix systems.  It's more secure than plain old FTP, if that matters.

Comment: Why using Java? There are dozens of existing utilies that will do it. There is no need to write new code for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a native Jenkins solution for it, not sure why you need Java: 
**Archive** your cvs file and use [Copy Artifact Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Copy+Artifact+Plugin) to add it into the WS of the selenium job.

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest solution is using dropbox or some service like that. You can copy with an execute shell command to dropbox folder in your jenkins job. And it will automatically synchronize with other machines you installed.

```
cp ~/Home/jobs/YourJob/workspace/yourproject/build/outputs/foo.csv /User/youruser/Dropbox
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the new Pipeline Plugin (aka Workflow) and do something like:

```
node('master') {
    //stash what ever you need
    stash includes: 'path/to/things/*', name: 'binary'
}


node('selenium') {
   //get it in selenium server
   unstash 'binary'
}
```

Note: You have to configure 'selenium' as slave

You can have more information:

https://www.cloudbees.com/blog/parallelism-and-distributed-builds-jenkins